# Prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}((4 + \frac{1}{n^{2}})^{3}) = 64$ using definition of limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Here is the question:

Given $a_{n} = (4 + \frac{1}{n^{2}})^{3}$ Make use of the definition of the limit to explain why:

$\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n} = 64$

Here's what I've done so far:

> $(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})^3$
>
> $= (4 + \frac{1}{n^2})(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})$
>
> $= (16 + \frac{8}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^4})(4 + \frac{1}{n^2})$
>
> $= 64 + \frac{48}{n^2} + \frac{12}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^6}$

Then:

> $|a_n -64|<\epsilon$
>
> $|64 + \frac{48}{n^2} + \frac{12}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^6} -64|<\epsilon$
>
> $|\frac{48}{n^2} + \frac{12}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^6}|<\epsilon$
>
> $\frac{48}{n^2} + \frac{12}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^6}<\epsilon$

And here I'm stuck. I can't see anywhere to simplify the left side in order to isolate `n`, which I know I need to answer the question.

Comment: Assume $n>1$ and you can get rid of some... stuff. Also, you don't have to start off with $\epsilon$ in the right-hand side, that can be added at the end when you want to wrap things up.

Comment: Notice that $\dfrac{48}{n^2}+\dfrac{12}{n^4}+\dfrac{1}{n^6}<\dfrac{48+12+1}{n^2}$ so perhaps you should select an $\epsilon$ such that  $\dfrac{61}{n^2}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume $n>1$ as suggested in the comments, we know that
$$\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^6}<\frac{61}{n^2}$$
This comes from the statement that for $n>1$
$$n^2<n^4<n^6$$
You can probably finish from here.

Comment: You can go a step further by noting that $n^{2}>n$ so that the expression is less than $61/n$.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to show that $\dfrac{1}{n^2}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

Indeed for any $\varepsilon >0$ we have $\dfrac{1}{n^2}<\varepsilon$ for $n>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt \varepsilon}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From where you stopped, take $N> \max\left\{1,\sqrt{\frac{12^2}{\epsilon}}\right\}$. Then for all $n>N$,

$\frac{48}{n^2}+\frac{12}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^6} = \frac{48}{n^2}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{4n^2}+\frac{1}{48n^4}\right)< \frac{48(3) }{n^2}=\frac{12^2 }{n^2} <\frac{12^2 }{N^2} < \epsilon $.

So $L=64$.